# Stream video with custom data

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, multimedia

The end goal is to live stream video with custom data in stream from mobile to another client. I need record data from sensors and this data have to be inline with video in terms of time. If I understood correctly I can have lets say 2 tracks/streams: video and custom data. Then I can mux them in one stream with GStreamer. Custom data is just basic class with 5 properties strings and int and I will gather this data lets say every millisecond. The question is how can I represent my custom data in order to combine video and custom data into one stream?

I am very new to all this multimedia things.